# Using Excel vba link cell in one list object table to another list object table

Tags: vba, cell

I have created vba code to copy a row in the Sheet 1 to Sheet  . The problem is that I need to be able to link the row copied, so that when Sheet 1 changes the copied row will be updated automatically. This would mean that I would need to somehow reference the row in Sheet 1 to Sheet 2. I have tried .Formula . Address, but these all copy either the value or the the cell reference into the Sheet 2.  Here it the code that I have:

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyCell()

   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   Dim WListo As ListObject
   Dim Lrow As Long
   Dim lngLast As Long



   'Find the last used row in Sheet1
   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With


    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table4")
    lngLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lngLast) <> "" Then

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table4").ListRows.Add
    End With

    End If

    With Worksheets("Advisory").Range("Table4")
       nLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
       End With


End With
    'This adds the last row
    i = LastRow
       With Worksheets("Sheet1")
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value > "" Then

**///This is where I am having the problem

      'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Rows(i).Address(True, True, True, True)

      'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nLastRow).Address = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

      'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nLastRow) = Rows(i).FormulaR1C1
      'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nLastRow).Value = Rows(i).Value
      'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nLastRow) = Rows(i).FormulaR1C1
      'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nLastRow) = Rows(i).Address(, False, False, True)



               **/This works if I just want to copy the rows but it is not linked
               'Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nLastRow)
               'nLastRow = nLastRow + 1

           End If
       End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Rows(i).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & nLastRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This will paste a link to the source row into the range on your target sheet.

I don't think there's a direct way to paste links using the `Copy` function arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. I just had to set External to True! .Address(External:=True)